# The NSDATA is not writing into Documents Dir, when iPhone on Background mode with Locked State?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I tried following methods:

[image]

2. In **Appdelegate.m**

   ```
   -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {

   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier  taskId = 0;
   taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       taskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];

   }
   ```
3. Actually I am using **NSURLSession** to download the File

   ```
   -(void)methodForDownloadTheFile:(NSString *)fileName
   {

       // 1
       NSString *fileApi =
       @"https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox";

       NSString *escapedPath = [fileName
                                stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",
                           fileApi,escapedPath];

       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlStr];

       [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

       if (self.dataTask) {
           [self.dataTask cancel];
       }

       // 2
       self.dataTask =[_session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

           if (!error) {
               NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
               if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                   // 3

                   //  [_filleddata appendData:data];

                   NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

                   NSString *localPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


               if( [data writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES])
               {
                   NSLog(@"HOpefully written into Documentz directory..");

               }
                   else
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Writting file mechanism - Failed!");
                   }

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                       NSLog(@"Downloaded Successfully");

                   });

               } else {
                   // HANDLE BAD RESPONSE //
               }
           } else {
               // ALWAYS HANDLE ERRORS :-] //
           }
           // 4
       }] ;
       if (self.dataTask) {
           [self.dataTask resume];
       }


   }
   ```

And Even The **Delegate - Downloading Progress ALSO NOT getting fired...**

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
     downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
     didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
  NSLog(@"%f / %f", (double)totalBytesWritten,
    (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have data protection enabled in your capabilities, so the documents directory will *not* be accessible while the device is locked *unless you flag it appropriately*.

Have a look at `NSFileProtectionNone attribute` and the `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method in `NSFileManager`.

Or, if you don't require data protection (i.e. the data in your app isn't considered sensitive) turn off the data protection capability.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. @Paulw11. But I tried with NSFileProtectionNone Attribute for saving the NSData to Documents Dir **NO USE** And I turned off the Data Protection **IT ALSO NOT WORKING.** SORRY.

Comment: After you have turned off the data protection you should delete your app from the device/simulator and re-install

Comment: I deleted the app in my Device And also i turned of the Data Protection. **Not Working ** Sorry

Comment: You need to do a bit of debugging and logging - is the file access that is failing or is your background network traffic not downloading?

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion. Actually I am using **NSURLConnection -  DataTaskWithURL mechanism**. **Can you check with my code.** And even I checked memory Progress. It is Increasing ,Once it will finish the downloading. I got message from **GCD**.

Comment: How have you created your NSURLSession?  Is it an NSURLBackgroundSession?

Comment: I followed this link:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial. I don't know how to create NSURLBackgroundSession. I referred but I did not get proper material for using the BackgroundSession. So,Can you suggest some links to use the NSURLBackgroundSession.